# Cache with timeout per key

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, cache, go

I wrote a general purpose library for in-memory cache with custom timeout for each key.

```
import (
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

type item struct {
    value   interface{}
    expired bool
    owner   *Cache
    timer   *time.Ticker
}

//Cache of items which can be expired or cancelled (pulled)
type Cache struct {
    generator uint64
    lock      sync.RWMutex
    data      map[string]item
}

//NewCache - create new cache
func NewCache() *Cache {
    return &Cache{data: make(map[string]item)}
}

//Put value to cache with specified time-to-live and return generated unique
// (in terms of one cache) key.
func (cache *Cache) Put(value interface{}, ttl time.Duration) string {
    key := strconv.FormatUint(atomic.AddUint64(&cache.generator, 1), 10)
    it := item{
        value: value,
        owner: cache,
        timer: time.NewTicker(ttl)}
    cache.lock.Lock()
    cache.data[key] = it
    cache.lock.Unlock()
    go func() {
        defer it.timer.Stop()
        <-it.timer.C
        if !it.expired {
            it.owner.Pull(key)
        }
    }()
    return key
}

//Pull key from cache and remove it if it not already expired.
//Returns value and status
func (cache *Cache) Pull(key string) (interface{}, bool) {
    cache.lock.RLock()
    it, ok := cache.data[key]
    cache.lock.RUnlock()
    if !ok {
        return nil, false
    }
    cache.lock.Lock()
    it.expired = true
    it.timer.Stop()
    delete(cache.data, key)
    cache.lock.Unlock()
    return it.value, true
}
```

General questions:

1. Could be here a memory leak due to timers channels?
2. Is a creating new timer for each item a true GOlang way?

Comment: Why not use memcached or redis?

Comment: If you're worried about memory leaks, try a memory analysis tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Can be very useful, though I haven't tried it on Go code before.

Comment: @jacwah , I would like to use my application without external dependencies